# Difference between Scala 2 implicits and Scala 3 given/using

Tags: scala, implicit, scala-3

What is the difference between the `implicit` keyword in Scala 2 and `given`+`using` in Scala 3? Is it just that `implicit` has been split up into two keywords, or are the semantics also different, and if so, how?

Answer (score 6):

For the most part, they are the same. However, `implicit` is no longer used for multiple different concepts. The [docs](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/contextual/relationship-implicits.html) go into more detail, but here's a summary of them:

#### Using

When declaring parameters, `using` is just the same as `implicit`. However, when explicitly passing an implicit argument, you must use `using`:

```scala
def foo(using bar: Bar) = ???
foo(using Bar()) //Cannot use just foo(Bar()) as you would in Scala 2
```

You can also have implicit by-name parameters in Scala 3.

---

#### Given

Givens are also pretty similar to implicit vals/objects/methods.

One nice thing about them is that they can be anonymous, and the compiler will generate a name for them, which looks something like `given_F_X_Y` if the type of the given were `F[X, Y]`. More details [here](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/contextual/relationship-implicits.html#anonymous-given-instances).

Another change is that the type of a given must be written explicitly - it cannot be inferred like for an implicit in Scala 2.

A given without parameters maps to an `implicit object`. `given foo: Foo with {...}` becomes just `implicit object foo extends Foo {...}`.

A given with parameters is akin to an `implicit def` that takes in only more `implicit` parameters.

```
given listOrd[T](using ord: Ord[T]): Ord[List[T]] with { ... }
//^^ this maps to this vv
class listOrd[T](implicit ord: Ord[T]) extends Ord[List[T]] { ... }
final implicit def listOrd[T](implicit ord: Ord[T]): listOrd[T] = new listOrd[T]
```

A given that is merely an alias becomes an `implicit def` if it is just a reference, or an `implicit lazy val` otherwise.

```
val foo: Foo
given Foo = foo
```

would become `final implicit def given_Foo = foo` (note the compiler-generated name), but

```
given foo: Foo = new Foo()
```

would turn into `final implicit lazy val foo: Foo = new Foo()` because `new Foo()` shouldn't be computed unnecessarily.

---

Instead of using an `implicit def` for an implicit conversion from `A` to `B`, you can now define a given [`Conversion[A, B]`](http://dotty.epfl.ch/api/scala/Conversion.html) instance.

You can also still use implicit classes in Dotty, but you can directly define [extension methods](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/contextual/extension-methods.html). While methods inside extensions cannot take their own type parameters, they are easier to use than implicit classes.

An additional change in Scala 3 - `summon` is a method like `implicitly`, but it can return a type more specific than the one being requested.

Answer (score 2):

Semantics is also different. In Scala 2 `Not` can be defined with ambiguity trick

```
trait Not[A]
object Not {
  implicit def default[A]: Not[A] = null
  implicit def ambig[A](implicit a: A): Not[A] = null
}

implicitly[Not[Int]] // compiles

implicit val s: String = null
// implicitly[Not[String]] // doesn't compile
```

But in Scala 3 this doesn't work because ambiguity error is not propagated

```
trait Not[A]
object Not {
  given [A]: Not[A] = null
  given [A](using a: A): Not[A] = null
  // given ambig[A](using a: A): Not[A] = null
}

summon[Not[Int]] // compiles

given String = null
summon[Not[String]] // compiles
```

One should use `scala.util.NotGiven` instead

```
summon[NotGiven[Int]] // compiles

given String = null
// summon[NotGiven[String]] // doesn't compile
```

(Tested in 3.0.0-M3-bin-20201211-dbc1186-NIGHTLY)

http://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/contextual/givens.html#negated-givens

http://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/changed-features/implicit-resolution.html

Comment: Nice, I didn’t think of this! I think there is also an example on the Changes in Implicit Resolution page somewhere about how an ambiguity error doesn’t let a search succeed in Scala 3

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HQojyuZK-Uo  Scala 3: Anti-Givens by 
Rock the JVM

Comment: https://blog.rockthejvm.com/anti-givens/